# benchmarking between SLAM alghoritms

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to make a benchmark between GMAPPING and Cartographer SLAM alghoritms.
I have made 2D maps with gmapping and cartographer on ROS kinetic.(occupancy grid map format , i have saved maps with map_saver)
I need a roadmap about how to compare maps. Also I have to make a ground-truth map and compare the maps against this ground truth map.

My questions;

1. How can I make a ground truth map, which tools can be used?
2. How can I compare pgm files(maps) I know that first I have to allign my maps and then compare but how?

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318916/benchmarking-between-slam-alghoritms/) by [zeynep](https://answers.ros.org/users/28278/zeynep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2019-03-20

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know it's quite late to answer this but I recently did compare two results from two SLAM packages. For the comparison I used a Python package called [evo](https://michaelgrupp.github.io/evo/) that is meant to be used to compare odometry and SLAM.

I have described my full workflow in [this post](https://msadowski.github.io/Comparing-SLAM-with-ROS-evo/) but in short it consists of the following steps:

- Record a bag file while the robot is moving around space
- Replay the data while running slam packages of your choice, record these as bag files again
- Run a script that will convert the logged tf to a message supported by evo on every bag file
- Merge two bag files

What I was missing in my experiments is groundtruth but if you have this information you will easily be able to add it.

---

Originally posted by [msadowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/19897/msadowski/) with karma: 311 on 2019-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't really know to answer your first question, but I would suggest to try running several SLAM algorithms and keep as ground truth the one that you think performs better.

As for the second question, there exists this package https://github.com/robotics-4-all/ogm_merging that implements the evaluation between two different OGMs.
It is applying the Nearest Neighbor method, for every point of the map that is considered to be an obstacle, calculates the distance between these points and finds the Overall Mean Square Error.

---

Originally posted by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) with karma: 210 on 2019-03-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [seamus](https://answers.ros.org/users/40603/seamus/) on 2019-03-25**:
@kosmastsk your feeedback is greatly appreciated. I was able to build and run
the mentioned package (env: ros kinetic, opencv 2.4.13 , cv_bridge build with opencv 2.4.13) in order to benchmark SLAM-generated OGM maps (cartographer vs. gmapping).  Alignment and map merge is successful, but the difference is it shown in Result Field of  "Feature Matching MSE" window and is it in meters? Thanks in advance

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2019-03-25**:
@seamus glad that this package helped you. Yes, the result is shown there and MSE is calculated in meters, and the Quality Metric is a normalized MSE. So, I would suggest to take into account the Q, when you evaluate maps, as a more well defined and bounded metric

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best way to have ground truth is to make the ground the robot rolls on (literally) :) Make a Gazebo world for your robot to roll around in so that you know exactly where everything is to compare to. Then run the different SLAM implementations over the *exact same* mapping run's data of that space and compare.

As for comparison techniques, many are available, I'd recommend consulting other SLAM benchmarking papers for their methodologies and using one or a variant of one for formal comparison.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-03-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @stevemacenski said, easiest way to test their accuracy is a simulation environment which you could directly access to the ground truth data. This was what I did to compare effects of navigation's parameters' changes 3 years ago.

But; maybe in a testing environment, you could measure exact positions of multiple points in a room, then navigate the robot manually to those positions continuously on maps generated by both those algorithms. After navigating between those points enough, you could have enough data to compare the performance.

Or let's say that this is an academic project and you could create an environment which you can place different sized AR tags everywhere. You can continuously collect the differences between navigation beliefs on generated maps by both packages and AR tag positioning reports.

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2019-10-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1